# Angular Electron, white screen after reload page

Tags: angular, screen, electron, reload

When I first run my application electron with angular 4, it works normally
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKg6S.jpg)

but once I reload the page all becomes white

When I check the DOM, everything appears normal, but the screen is still white.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP5vF.jpg)

What causes the problem, how do I fix it ?

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console log?

Comment: Thank for your quick answer,

Comment: There is no error in the console, all appear normal.
I can even inspect the elements of the DOM but on the interface there is nothing

Comment: I had the same issue and found this simple change and it works. [https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/issues/15](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/issues/15)

Answer (score 9):

I know this is pretty old... but this is the most direct question I could find.

I was running thru the same issue; every change to my angular application required me to rebuild the entire electron app, and if I refreshed the electron app was getting an empty screen.

The issue it is related to when the html5 routing (no hash #) in angular is enabled. If Electron refreshes, it will try to run an URL like this: `file://local-filesystem-project-location-without-index-html/{angular-route}` and that doesn't exist in the file system. You need to "force" to load (include) the `index.html` part in the URL.

I am sure there are other ways, but this is how I did it:

#### Step 1: change the `<base href="/">` in `index.html`

1. Change to: `<base href=""> or <base href="index.html">`

#### Step 2: For routing to work, switch to hash location strategy in angular

1. Option 1: `app.module.ts`

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    }
]
```

2. Option 2: `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`

#### Step 3: for navigation routes when you open a new window, remember to append the `#` in Electron.

1. Example: `mainWindow.loadURL("file:///index.html#/my-route")`

This worked for me... hopefully it can help someone facing the same issue.

Comment: This worked for me in development, but after windows build this approach doesnt work the window.location.href is pointing to 

   D:/Code/TimerlyApp/release-builds/timerly-desktop-win-win32-ia32/resources/app.asar/#/"

Comment: I really don't like this # on my routes :(

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution on this topic on [github](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/issues/15)

You have to add
`win.webContents.on('did-fail-load', () => win.loadURL(...));` *[@mariotaku](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/issues/15#issuecomment-850513476)*

So when your app does not found the right route, it will reload your entire app.

#### Explanation of the bug

When you do reload your app, electron does not know what to load, so he try to load your actual route, which could be `/home` and can not find it anymore. Subscribing to a `did-fail-load` will make your app restart, with the correct url, which will find the right file to load.

Comment: this suggestion solved it for me. I now have a function like this `function loadnow(win) {
  win.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : \`file://${path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html')}\`);
}` I simply call it in createWindow, and also on `'did-fail-load'`

Comment: Solved for me too without adding too much complexity in existing code.

Answer (score -1):

we can prevent by reload issue by globalShortcut

```
import { app, BrowserWindow,globalShortcut } from 'electron';

app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.DEBUG_PROD === 'true') {
    await installExtensions();
  }
  globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+R', () => false);
  globalShortcut.register('F5', () => false);
 }
```

Comment: This will cause the shortcuts to stop working for other apps too.