# Angular electron white screen but loads after reloading

Tags: angular, electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

I am trying to build my angular app with electron. I am using `electron-forge package` to create the build. When I execute the .exe file I can only see a white screen but after reloading the app loads correctly. If I reload the app again I can only see a white screen.

`app-routing.module.ts` has `useHash` enabled and the `index.html` has `<base href="./">`.

This is the electron index.ts:

```js
import { BrowserWindow, app } from 'electron';
import path from 'path';

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) app.quit();

let mainWindow: BrowserWindow | null;

const createWindow = (): void => {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    resizable: true,
    title: 'My app title'
  });

  // const startURL = app.isPackaged ? `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../../dist', 'index.html')}` : `http://localhost:4200`;
  const startURL = `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../../dist', 'index.html')}`;

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  mainWindow.loadURL(startURL);
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', () => createWindow());

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
});
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

I have tried to change the base href, chaning the loadURL to add '#' as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61194524/8124884 but it is not working.

Comment: Check the Console and Network tabs when you get the white screen, any errors or wrong paths?